# powershell : comma and parameters inside a class brackets?

Tags: powershell, windows-runtime

i saw that script somewhere :

```
[Windows.Globalization.Calendar,Windows.Globalization,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::New().GetTimeZone()
```

And i was wondering what is the 2 parameters that was write after `Windows.Globalization.Calendar` ?

Also, if you know it, could you give me the C# equivalent of this `[Class, ???, ???]::new()`?

Comment: It's a _fully-qualified type name_ - it means "resolve type `Windows.Globalization.Calendar` from the WinRT library `Windows.Globalization`"

Comment: See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance) for information about consuming WinRT types in C#/.NET

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen No, it's not a fully-qualified type name in .NET parlance. It obviously doesn't follow [the grammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/specifying-fully-qualified-type-names#grammar-for-type-names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer 1

It's some undocumented trick. The syntax isn't defined anywhere. The first two components in `[Windows.Globalization.Calendar, Windows.Globalization, ContentType=WindowsRuntime]` can be easily deduced: these are full name of the class and its namespace. BTW, namespace seems redundant here. `[Windows.Globalization.Calendar, $Null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime]` works for me as well.

The third component apparently hints at [Windows Runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime). Its format looks like a magic constant – it's hard to be more definite as Windows PowerShell is closed-source. One can find this string in the names of Windows Runtime assemblies:

```
PS > [Windows.Globalization.Calendar, $Null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime].Assembly.FullName
Windows.Globalization, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime

PS > [Windows.Globalization.Calendar, $Null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime].AssemblyQualifiedName
Windows.Globalization.Calendar, Windows.Globalization, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime
```

I suppose that upon encountering `ContentType=WindowsRuntime` PowerShell (or .NET Framework on its behalf) tries to resolve the given class name as a Windows Runtime type. OS-wide metadata for Windows Runtime reside in `%SystemRoot%\system32\WinMetadata`. Metadata for particular namespace can be located using `WindowsRuntimeMetadata` class:

```
PS > [System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMetadata]:: `
     ResolveNamespace('Windows.Globalization', $Null)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Globalization.winmd
```

It also should be noted that this syntax [won't work](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13042) starting with PowerShell 7.1/.NET 5.0. You would need to add the type in a conventional way

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll
```

and then just use `[Windows.Globalization.Calendar]`.

For reference also see [What is powershell syntax doing something like Assembly::LoadWithPartialName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67795868/what-is-powershell-syntax-doing-something-like-assemblyloadwithpartialname).

#### Answer 2

That will be

```
new Windows.Globalization.Calendar()
```

Using `Windows.Globalization` namespace requires a reference to `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll`