# What is powershell syntax doing something like Assembly::LoadWithPartialName?

Tags: powershell, windows-runtime

I found this piece of code over Internet. And it works

```
[void][Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation, Windows, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
[Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation]::GetInternetConnectionProfile().GetConnectionCost()
```

Please, can you explain, what `[Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation, Windows, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]` means and where can I read about it.

Comment: Add-Type -AssemblyName "Windows.Networking.Connectivity...."

Comment: @RetiredGeek ... and it does not work.

Comment: Did you type the correct assembly name? Try this one Add-Assembly -AssemblyName "PrenentationCore"

Comment: @RetiredGeek Yes, tried `Add-Type -AssemblyName  'Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation'`, `Add-Type -AssemblyName  'Windows.Networking.Connectivity'`, `Add-Type -AssemblyName  'Windows.Networking'` - none works. `Add-Assembly` cmdlet does not exist.

Comment: The scripting guys have a nice article on it: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/more-messing-around-with-wireless-settings-with-powershell/

Comment: @abraham-zinala, there is no any information in this article describing why this class is loading so weird way.

Comment: @Filimonic, tbh, not sure why it's doing that. You may have to reinstall .net. Worked just fine for me on 3 laptops, and 4 desktops I tested it on.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala thats because youre testing on powershell ISE not on powershell :)

Comment: @Santiago, don't call me out like that:/ lol you're right! My bad

Comment: @filimonic See my attempt at decrypting it – https://stackoverflow.com/a/76552023/